# Derive column after Applying Partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, derived-column

I have data as follows:

```
+----+--------+------------------+
| Id | Weight | is_weight_faulty |
+----+--------+------------------+
| A  |    100 |                1 |
| A  |     50 |                0 |
| A  |     10 |                0 |
| B  |    500 |                0 |
| B  |    200 |                0 |
| B  |     40 |                0 |
| C  |    100 |                0 |
+----+--------+------------------+
```

I need to create a column correct weight which depends on two factors `Id` and value `is_weight_faulty`. First I will apply partition by `Id` and order by `is_weight_faulty`. If for any subset we find value `1` in column `is_weight_faulty` our correct weight would be `Weight` = `Correct_Weight` where `is_weight_faulty = 1` and for remaining entries of that subset `Correct_Weight` would be 0.

If we look at first three rows for `Id` A `Correct_Weight` would equal 100 in 1st row while for next 2 rows it would be 0. For remaining cases `Correct_Weight` would equal `Weight` as there is no record of `is_weight_faulty = 1` against each subset of data that we would get after applying partition by.

**Desired Output**

```
+----+--------+------------------+----------------+
| Id | Weight | is_weight_faulty | Correct_Weight |
+----+--------+------------------+----------------+
| A  |    100 |                1 |            100 |
| A  |     50 |                0 |              0 |
| A  |     10 |                0 |              0 |
| B  |    500 |                0 |            500 |
| B  |    200 |                0 |            200 |
| B  |     40 |                0 |             40 |
| C  |    100 |                0 |            100 |
+----+--------+------------------+----------------+
```

I am unable to create cases that would make `Correct_Weight` 0 in case if there is an entry of `is_weight_faulty = 1`

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max()over()` window function to find out the highest value of `is_weight_correct` column for each `id`. If it's 1 then multiply `weight` with `is_weight_correct` with the help of `case when else` statement.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table mytable ( Id varchar(10), Weight int, is_weight_faulty int);
 
 insert into mytable values( 'A'  ,    100 ,                1 );
 insert into mytable values( 'A'  ,     50 ,                0 );
 insert into mytable values( 'A'  ,     10 ,                0 );
 insert into mytable values( 'B'  ,    500 ,                0 );
 insert into mytable values( 'B'  ,    200 ,                0 );
 insert into mytable values( 'B'  ,     40 ,                0 );
 insert into mytable values( 'C'  ,    100 ,                0 );
```

Query:

```
 select id, weight, is_weight_faulty, 
 (case when max(is_weight_faulty)over(partition by id)=1 then weight*is_weight_faulty else weight end) correct_weight
 from mytable
 GO
```

Output:

| id | weight | is_weight_faulty | correct_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 1 | 100 |
| A | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 500 | 0 | 500 |
| B | 200 | 0 | 200 |
| B | 40 | 0 | 40 |
| C | 100 | 0 | 100 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7da413fcfec8312850628e5816a26116)*

Comment: can you explain this part of your code `(partition by id)=1`

Comment: (max(is_weight_faulty)over(partition by id)) is calculating max(is_weight_faulty) for each ID. If it's 1 that means for that particular id at least one row has 1 in is_weight_faulty column